# Is there any notion of "smoothification" from $\mathbb{R}$-schemes to generalized smooth spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I will write $\operatorname{Diff}$ to denote a category of generalized smooth spaces e.g. $Sh(\mathsf{CartSp})$. Is there a version of $\operatorname{Diff}$ for which there exists a functor $\mathcal{S^{\infty}}:\mathbb{R-}Sch \to \operatorname{Diff}$ which could legitimately be called ***the* smoothing functor**?

I'm not nearly experienced enough in any of the relevant fields to conjecture what such a functor must satisfy so I'm deliberately leaving the vaguenesss in the above question. However, for the sake of completeness I will state some properties I think are relavant here:

- Sends the affine space to euclidean space
- Sends smooth integral finite type proper $\mathbb{R}$-schemes to compact (analytic) smooth manifolds.
- Complexification followed by analytification and then the forgetful functor from complex analytic spaces to $\operatorname{Diff}$ should in some way relate to this smoothing functor. (I'm not even sure that there's a "forgetful" functor from complex analytic spaces to generalized smooth spaces so this is conjectural too).
- Sends proper maps to proper maps

Already I have the feeling that philosophically this is wrong since it seems to me that the study of real singularities goes very often through complexification. Arguments for why such a functor would be an atrocity are very welcome as well.

Comment: I would think the obvious thing would be to send a finite type affine scheme to its set of real points as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the induced smooth structure), and then to extend to arbitrary schemes by taking colimits.

Comment: You will probably lose information of the sort that $C^\infty$ schemes would preserve, and so you might have a factorisation of the sort $Schemes/\mathbb{R} \to C^\infty Schemes \to Diff$

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought as much, and there might not even be a better option here. My question then is what are the properties of such a functor? There are a lot of theorems about the analytification functor and it seems to be not so bad. Can the same be said here?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're asking, you might find something here http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/wdgillam/diffspace.pdf (and references)

Comment: @DavidRoberts I know almost nothing about $C^{\infty}$-schemes. Is there an obvious functor $C^{\infty}Sch \to Diff$ with good properties?

Comment: @MattiaTalpo Thanks, this certainly looks helpful.

Comment: @SaalHardali well, I was even thinking of the Cahiers topos (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cahiers+topos), or other well-adapted models of Synthetic Differential Geometry. There are certainly good functors between the category of diffeological spaces and the Cahiers topos.

Comment: Saal, I've noticed that you've deleted a number of posts recently that the community has upvoted and therefore finds worthwhile. I hope you reconsider, as the point of MathOverflow is to be a repository of useful mathematical knowledge, and deleting useful posts defeats that purpose.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I'm sorry about that. I just lost interest in the question so I decided to delete so as to contribute my share of edits. I apologize for my selfishness. I will undelete them.